# PHP wont delete mysql rows

Tags: php, mysql

Everything seems OK, but it won't delete rows. MySQL version is 5.1. Script is:

```
<?php

$host="localhost";
$username="***";
$password="***";
$db_name="***";

$db = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql = "DELETE FROM oc_ixml_cat_map WHERE name='***'";
$result=mysql_query($sql,$db) or die(mysql_error());

if ($result) {
    echo "OK";
}
else {
    echo "Not OK";
}

?>
```

Comment: Put the error, please...

Comment: i don't understand the problem. what error are you getting? don't put *** as a variable replacement because otherwise we have no idea what it referes to.

Comment: `***` is an absolutely fine replacement for a string literal that they don't want to reveal. `'abc'` or `'***'` makes no difference in understanding of the problem or its solution

Comment: There is no error, result is OK, but the data is still in database. I just replaced actual data with ***

Comment: Then there is only one explanation. There are now rows with the `name` value you provided. There is no other possible reason with that code at that point.

Comment: I am using žšč in the sql statement. Is that the problem?

Comment: And do you have that same name in database too? All those 3 special chars?

Comment: Yes...the name is the same in database. When i execute command in phpmyadmin ore mysql command like works like a charm. Yes...they are special chars

Comment: to debug this - run it as a select first. If no rows are returned then start to check character sets consistency between PHP and the RDBMS?

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the string to:

DELETE FROM oc_ixml_cat_map WHERE id=1

Where 1 is an available ID of your table just to see if the command is running or it is connection problem...

Comment: I am using žšč chars in the sql statement. Is that the problem?

Comment: Have you tried change to id? Does it work correctly?....  Try change the equal to like command:

DELETE FROM oc_ixml_cat_map WHERE name like  " "